# Function that would handle returning object of different classes in c++

Tags: c++

I`m having a question if there is any way of making function that would be able to return obj of different classes in one method.As far is we should explicitly show what will function return like

```
int foo();
```

And right now I'm doing by course project - implementing type of bank system. I have faced a problem when i have data structure (hashtable) that consist of linked lists of user depending on type of their account

```
class HashTable{
private 
    LinkedList<User> *user_array;
    LinkedList<Stuff> *stuff_array;
    ....
```

and i want to create a function that would return me a pointer to 1 person 
with would look like this

```
auto getPersonByKey(string login, string password, string list_type) 
// auto is suposed to be some pointer for account
   {
     int index = hash(login, password);
     if (list_type == "User")
     {
        return user_array[index].getPerson(login, password);
        //returns pointer for User obj
     }
     else if (list_type == "Stuff")
     {
        return stuff_array[index].getPerson(login, password);
        //returns pointer for Stuff obj
     }
     else
       return nullptr;
```

}

Unless there is no way to return obj in this way should i make some class that would be inherited from all types of account 
or should i overload function for each case .

Comment: `auto` would only deduce one specific type. That's done at compile time and cannot be decided at runtime.

Comment: You could technically return a `void *` but I would advise against it. Additionally, your `LinkedList` members should probably not be pointers, unless the lists are owned by another class.

Comment: You can: 1. use a base class for all your LinkedList<*> and return a pointer to base class. 2. use std::variant or boost::variant to create a discriminant union for all your LinkedList<*>. 3. eventually make your `list_type` a tag (dummy struct) and use tag dispatch at compile time. Of course the last option is not always possible ...